# Get the total number of products published in a category of my woocommerce store

Tags: woocommerce, count, product

**I am using the following code:**

```
/* Woocommerce - Add Product Count View in Each Category */
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'add_product_count_view', 20);

function add_product_count_view() {
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat');
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {
    if(is_tax('product_cat', $term->name)) {
        echo '<span class="count-view">'.$term->count
            .__( ' items')
            .'</span>';
        }
    }
}
```

This code shows the total items in the store of the categories.

If a category has 20 items, 15 active and 5 inactive, it shows that there are 20 items in that category.

What I need is that it only shows the number of active articles in that category.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution is `wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' )`, which is returns total products of any WooCommerce archive pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the count of products published on the product category page visited via the `WC_Product_Query` class (using the [**`wc_get_products`**](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query) function):

```
// shows the number of products published on the product category page
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'add_product_count_view', 20);
function add_product_count_view() {

    // only on the product category page
    if ( ! is_product_category() ) {
        return;
    }

    // gets the slug of the current product category
    $category_slug = get_queried_object()->slug;

    // gets the number of products published in the current category
    $args = array(
        'status'   => 'publish',
        'category' => array( $category_slug ),
        'return'   => 'ids',
        'limit'    => -1,
    );
    $products = wc_get_products( $args );

    echo '<span class="count-view">' . count($products) . __( ' items', 'woocommerce' ) . '</span>';

}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*